# Why can't I add the two random values created by my methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio

SO I'm trying to add the two values returned by my functions but it keeps throwing an error.
I don't understand why it wont add them??
I need to be able to add the two values together so that I can take that sum 
and calculate if the sum of dice rolls is a winning number or not.

```
namespace CS_DiceGame_
{
    public partial class diceThrowMainWindow : Form
    {
        // This is a dice throw game, that rolls a random dice number
        // then tells the user whether they won or loss
        // written by Dakota Wisdom Lorance
        // Oct. 13, 2014

        public diceThrowMainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int firstDieRoll ()
        {
            int firstDieValue;
            Random rand1 = new Random();
            firstDieValue = rand1.Next(6) + 1;

            switch (firstDieValue)
            {
                case 1:
                    firstDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = true;
                    firstDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    firstDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = true;
                    firstDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    firstDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = true;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    firstDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = true;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    firstDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = true;
                    firstDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    firstDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    firstDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }

            return firstDieValue;
        }

        private int secondDieRoll ()
        {
            int secondDieValue;
            Random rand2 = new Random();
            secondDieValue = rand2.Next(6) + 1;

            switch (secondDieValue)
            {
                case 1:
                    secondDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = true;
                    secondDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    secondDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = true;
                    secondDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;

                    break;

                case 3:
                    secondDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = true;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;

                    break;

                case 4:
                    secondDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = true;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;

                    break;

                case 5: 
                    secondDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = true;
                    secondDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = false;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    secondDiePictureBoxOne.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxTwo.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxThree.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFour.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxFive.Visible = false;
                    secondDiePictureBoxSix.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
            return secondDieValue;
        }

        private void currentRollValue ()
        {
            secondDieRollValue + firstDieRollValue;
        }

        private void throwDiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstDieRoll();
            secondDieRoll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think there is a mistake in your code: secondDieRollValue + firstDieRollValue; Did you need to return the result or assign it to another property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a random calculation in limbo.. not being assigned to anything here:

```
private void currentRollValue ()
{
    secondDieRollValue + firstDieRollValue; // <-- this does nothing.
}
```

First, you need to move your variables to *class level*, so they can be shared between methods:

```
public partial class diceThrowMainWindow : Form
{
    int firstDieValue = 0;
    int secondDieValue = 0;

    // .. the rest here
```

You then need to assign it to something then display it somewhere:

```
var result = secondDieValue + firstDieValue; 
someLabel.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: AH I thought I could add the two in a method and call it. However when I use your method I get the error that secondDieRollValue doesn't exist?

Comment: Also I really appreciate your help on this, this one has been a headbanger for me.

Comment: You need to declare the variable in your code ... I haven't done that (I assumed you had .. but it appears you haven't..).

Comment: In fact.. what I think you want is `var result = secondDieValue + firstDieValue;`. I will update my answer.

Comment: I did have them declared within their individual functions?

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to make them class level so they are shared across methods.

Comment: Annd I figured it out. I have to make sure the variable is in an accessible scope. . . I don't know why I didn't realize that. . .  Sometimes I feel really stupid. . .